# How can I make Word use wildcards to replace text?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Say I have a document that says

```
bit
bart
but
```

I want to replace the leading b with a p, and leave everything else the same.

```
If I:
find b*t
replace p*t
```

This returns

```
p*t
p*t
p*b
```

How can I make it leave the middle letters alone?

Edit: Someone linked to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

So, I tried

```
find:
b[a-z]t

replace
p[a-z]t
```

output:

```
p[a-z]t
```

Comment: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: No cigar. See edit

Comment: No cigar indeed. Go read it again. And then read  http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f

Answer (score 1):

find what:
`<b`
replace with:

```
p
```

Above will replace every first "b" in the words with the "p" letter.